# The limit of sequence in the recurrence relation form

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If a sequence is defined by $u_{n+1} = k u_n + 9$ where $k$ is constant , if $u_1 = 5 $ and the limit of the sequence as $n\to \infty$ is $15$ .Find the value of $k$ .

I know that i have to find the nth term rule first , then we take the limit , but i do not know how to go from the recurrence relation through the nth term ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the limit at $\infty$ is given to be 15, so taking limits ($n$ tends to $\infty$) on both sides, we get $15=15k+9$. Thus, $k=2/5$.

Note that since this is a convergent sequence [limit exists at $n\to\infty$], so $lim_{n\to\infty}u_n = lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n+1} = 15$.

Since we have found $k$, we can find the formula for the general term.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the value of k it is very easy to find it because lim$u_{n}\,=limu_{n+1}$=15 so 15k+9=15 and k=6/15=2/5. Now assume that the general term of the sequence is $u_{n}=c(a^n) +b$. Writing down the recursive formula we immediately get b=15. By the exponential part we obtain$ ca^{n+1}=\frac{2}{5}ca^n$ and therefore a=2/5. Thus the general form of the sequence is $ u_{n}=c(2/5)^{n}+15$ and for n=1 we get 5=(2/5)c+15 and c=-25. Thus $ u_{n}=(-25)(\frac{2}{5})^{n}+15$ which agrees with the first few terms of the recursive formula. And also $limu_n$=15.

Comment: I agree , I deleted it and I got the correct general form of the sequence!